# Dynamically build table after it recieves information from service

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, asynchronous, angularjs-directive

HTML Code:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>one</td>
            <td>two</td>
            <td>three</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="color in colors">
            <td>{{ color.one }}</td>
            <td>{{ color.two }}</td>
            <td>{{ color.three }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Controller:

```
var SomeController = function ($scope, SomeService, $window) {
    var colors= [];

    SomeService.someFunction().success(function (data, status, header, config) {
        colors= data;
    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        // handle error
    });
};
```

Basically, I need to dynamically create my table based on whatever is in the backend... however, the issue is that once I call the page, it automatically loads the columns and a second later or so, it'll get back from the service. Is there anyway I can either delay the load time or have the table "refresh" itself to show the new data.

Comment: do include `subscriptions ` into scope like `$scope.subscriptions= data` & then `ng-repeat`would be `tr ng-repeat="subscription in subscriptions">
            <td>{{ subscription.one}}</td>
            <td>{{ subscription.two }}</td>
            <td>{{ subscription.three }}</td>
        </tr>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you may be able to use [ngShow](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) and wait for your data to resolve on `$scope.colors` This should delay showing your table until the call is complete. Try the following...

```
<table 
    class="table table-bordered table-striped"
    ng-show="colors" class="ng-hide">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>one</td>
            <td>two</td>
            <td>three</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="color in colors">
            <td>{{ color.one }}</td>
            <td>{{ color.two }}</td>
            <td>{{ color.three }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

---

```
SomeService.someFunction().success(function (data, status, header, config) {
    $scope.colors = data; // let colors be defined on $scope
})
```

Comment: That worked! I will make sure I mark it as the right answer when I can. Thank you!